# Fragment replacement triggers onQueryTextChange on searchview

Tags: android, android-fragments, save, state, searchview

This is how I navigate through my app:

- Open fragment with list
- Filter list by a text entered in searchview
- Tap on listitem (list fragment gets replaced by detail fragment)
- Navigate back (detail fragment gets replaced by list fragment)

When I navigate from list- to detail-fragment, I want to keep the current filter of the searchview in a string variable. I store the value of the searchview when onQueryTextChange is executed.

The problem:
I can't store the actual filter-value because onQueryTextChange gets called when I navigate from list to detail because something cleared the text of the searchview.

```
// ...
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            searchReceived(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
// ...

public void searchReceived(String searchQuery)
{
    this.stateHolder.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    // more code...
}
```

When I want to restore the filter when navigating back, it just filters with an empty string because the wrong value got stored in `this.stateHolder.searchQuery`.

Stack:

```
onQueryTextChange():139, EmployeeListFragment$1 {com.example.exampleapp.fragment}
onTextChanged():1153, SearchView {android.widget}
access$2000():92, SearchView {android.widget}
onTextChanged():1638, SearchView$11 {android.widget}
sendOnTextChanged():7408, TextView {android.widget}
setText():3816, TextView {android.widget}
setText():3671, TextView {android.widget}
setText():80, EditText {android.widget}
setText():3646, TextView {android.widget}
setQuery():511, SearchView {android.widget}
onActionViewCollapsed():1250, SearchView {android.widget}
collapseItemActionView():1662, ActionBarView$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter {com.android.internal.widget}
collapseItemActionView():1258, MenuBuilder {com.android.internal.view.menu}
clear():521, MenuBuilder {com.android.internal.view.menu}
doInvalidatePanelMenu():789, PhoneWindow {com.android.internal.policy.impl}
run():221, PhoneWindow$1 {com.android.internal.policy.impl}
```

How can I prevent the searchview from being cleared by the system when navigating?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @starrystar I posted a possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544382/fragment-replacement-triggers-onquerytextchange-on-searchview#23558681

Answer (score 7):

After 2 days of Googling i got the solution that will definitely helps you.

I have just `cut and pasted` code from `onCreateOptionMenu()` to `onPrepareOptionMenu()`

I do not know why it happens, I think listener of `searchView` is not going to be `NULL` by the way you can change your code this way.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_all_order, menu);

    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_all_order_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Enter Order No");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

**and Remove:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried it in many ways but `onQueryTextChange` doesn't get called in each fragments of my app.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is ActionBar (and subcomponents) are collapsed when the fragment holding it is replaced. When this happens the SearchView query is cleared as seen in [onActionViewCollapsed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java#SearchView.onActionViewCollapsed%28%29). Workarounds include:

**Prevent collapsing**

Remove `setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);` from the searchview's creation code or `android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"` from its xml code.

*This will affect how/when the view's close/voicesearch buttons are displayed upon attempting to collapse it*

It would also be possible to prevent collapsing by overriding SearchView's onActionViewCollapsed() method to do nothing but would accomplish the same.

**Ignore query changes when appropriate**

When the fragment is not valid (being replaced) then ignore query changes that would otherwise cause the fragment to alter its saved query text or layout (changing the layout would cause an exception if the fragment doesn't actually have view content).

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (!isVisible()) {
        // The fragment was replaced so ignore
        return true;
    }
    // Text was actually changed, perform search
    return true;
}
```

This would be the better option as it doesn't affect the functionality of the searchview.

Comment: Checking !isVisible() is simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

I see you didn't find a solution yet, I have same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655992/opening-closing-navdrawer-with-invalidateoptionsmenu-cause-onrestore-call-on-s) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655992/opening-closing-navdrawer-with-invalidateoptionsmenu-cause-onrestore-call-on-s):

I found that when `invalidateOptionsMenu` is called also the method `onQueryTextChange` is called because the View launch `dispatchRestoreInstanceState` with the previous value after you've cleared the search for example. Do you call `invalidateOptionsMenu` maybe?

Maybe, **inside** `onQueryTextChange`, you can check a boolean on some current state of your application objects to know if the *method content* should be executed. In my case I use `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(..)` to allow the search.

Also you can implement the `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` on each Class you use, on a `Fragment` or on the Main Activity class, somewhere in the class you could set a boolean module variable that you will check inside `onQueryTextChange.`

Comment: I have posted my solution that may help you for your question.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the menu item attribute `showAsAction` from `android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"` to `android:showAsAction="always"`. Now the look and behavior of the searchview has changed a bit, but the searchQuery doesn't get cleared!

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` + `LiveData` + `ViewModel` :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        viewModel.setSearchQuery(query)
        return true
    }
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        if(searchView.isIconified || !isVisible) {
            // Don't call setSearchQuery when SearchView is collapsing/collapsed
            return true
        }
        viewModel.setSearchQuery(newText)
        return true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone experiences this same issue, the onQueryTextChange callback will be fired when replacing the Fragment when using the following action in your menu XML file when your SearchView is currently **expanded**:

```
android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

When you attempt to use **isVisible()** (Java) or **isVisible** (Kotlin) in the onQueryTextChange callback as a way to determine if the Fragment is actually visible or not, the value returned will always return **true**.

The reason for this is that the onQueryTextChange callback will be fired when you're SearchView is currently expanded when you attempt to change Fragment's.

The default action of **collapseActionView** at this stage is to **collapse** the SearchView when changing Fragment's.

**Solution**:

Simply call your SearchView **!isIconified** (Kotlin) method in your onQueryTextChange callback and only set your logic if it returns **false**, i.e. the SearchView is currently **expanded**. Full example described below:

```
yourSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        // Do search query here if you use a submit action
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        if (!yourSearchView.isIconified) {
            // Don't execute your search query here when SearchView is 
            // currently open
            return true
        }
        // Do search query here
        return true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
   // your codes
   if (!newText.isNullOrBlank()) {
      // when fragment change
      // this will not work
   }
   // your codes
   return true
}
```

When fragment changes searchView triggered I don't know why but by checking this `newText.isNullOrBlank()` I solved my problem maybe it can help someone

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Answer (score 0):

All the proposed solutions were unfortunately not helpful on my side, because I had to keep the `collapseActionView|ifRoom` attributes on my SearchView, and I didn't want to check nullability/emptiness of my SearchView query.

So everytime the query changes, or the fragment is replaced by another, the `onQueryTextChange` callback is executed -> and the query is emptied (which causes some issues )
So I've done this :

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
   override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
      return false
   }

   override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
      if (this@SearchFragment.isRemoving) {
         return true
      }

      // [Statements here]
      return true
   }
})
```

I'm checking if my Fragment is currently being removed from the Activity with `isRemoving`, and I directly return `true` in order to "do nothing" if the fragment is being removed/replaced by another.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {

            if (searchTF.isIconified())
                return false;

            // put the "real" onQueryTextChange actions here


            return true;


        }
```