# Why is my doInBackground called so many times?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer, android-lifecycle

I have a navigation drawer and onClick is as follows:

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
                long id) {
            //  System.out.println("Clicked");
            mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    displayView(position);
                }
            }, 200);

        }
    }
```

My displayView(position); method is:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            fragment = new FragmentTab1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentTab2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentTab3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentTab3();
            //create dialog 



            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Now in the `onCreateView` of my Fragment class I call:

`new ListLoader().execute(getActivity());`

Here is the implementation:

```
public class ListLoader extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, CurAdapter> {

        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Asycdialog.setMessage("Working");
            Asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            Asycdialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            Asycdialog.setCancelable(false);
            Asycdialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(CurAdapter result) {
            Asycdialog.cancel();
            lv.setAdapter(result);
        //  dbHelper.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected CurAdapter doInBackground(Context... params) {

            System.out.println("Loading list");
            dbHelper.open();
            final String status = fetch();
            Cursor mCur; 
            mCur = dbHelper.magicQuery(status); 
            Cur = new CurAdapter(getActivity(), mCur,0);    


            Cur.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    return dbHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint,status);
                }
            }); 


            return Cur;
        }


    }
```

The message Loading List appears each time I open and close the Navigation Drawer, what is making this to execute? I have put a System.out message in my `onCreateView` but that does not show up, while as I am calling the AsyncTask only from `onCreateView`. What do I miss here?

I also face a flicker onClick of NavDrawer item to Fragment transition, even though I am using the asynchronous method. I have to, against my wish use a loading progress dialog.

#### Edit:

Got the culprit:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                new ListLoader().execute(getActivity());
            }
            else {
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

#### Edit I fiddled around with  OnQueryTextListener and this is resolved.

```
    int ix =1; 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                if(ix == 2)
                    new ListLoader().execute(getActivity());


            }
            else {
                ix = 2;
                CursorAdapter filterAdapter = (CursorAdapter) Cur;
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;

        }
    };
```

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 2):

**The Reason:**

This is the observed behavior when using `Fragment`s with `NavigationDrawer`. Each time the `NavigationDrawer` is opened, the current `Fragment`'s `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` are called, and each time the drawer is closed, the current `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` and `onResume()` are called.

In a nutshell, the `Fragment` is destroyed and created anew with every open/close cycle of the drawer. That's why your `AsyncTask` is called repeatedly.

**The Solution(s):**

You have two options:

**1.** Save the state of each `Fragment` in `onSavedInstanceState()` and restore the saved data in `onCreate()`. Execute the `AsyncTask` only if `savedInstanceState` is null in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

**2.** Try using `Activity`s instead of `Fragment`s. `Activity`s are not created anew when the drawer is opened/closed.

Comment: I have a System.out statement in my onCreateView - that is the only entry point for my ListLoader AsyncTask (`new ListLoader().execute(getActivity());`) to execute as I call it from there. While as the System.out in the doInbackground method of ListLoader Class is called, I do not see any log pertaining to the system.out in my onCreateView.

Comment: @Skynet: I'd advise you to check the code again. The cycle I've described is correct, and is indeed the observed behavior of `Fragment`s with `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: Hello ZygoteInit, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655992/opening-closing-navdrawer-with-invalidateoptionsmenu-cause-onrestore-call-on-s). As per my observation, I reckon that onResume and onStart are called, however onCreate is not called. I dont get any debug logs from onCreate. Yes that is not tested on memory intense operations.

Comment: @Skynet: so did that answer work for you ? sorry for replying late btw ... :)

Comment: I did a bit of dirty trick to handle it, have updated my question.